# Jenkins groovy run bat file in loop

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Having a .txt file im going over each line in him, sending each line as an argument for my bat script.

running the following code, he receive the first argument, but when the bat fail in the first time it is no longer continue to run the rest of the file lines.

```
script
{
    def project_list_file = readFile"${flow_bm_folder}\\${env.PROJECTS_LIST}"
    def list = project_list_file.readLines();
    for(int i = 0;i < list.size(); i++)
    {
        bat "${flow_bm_folder}\\Env.bat ${list[i]}"
    }
}
```

output example:

```
18:27:55 [Windows] <MY_PATH>><MY_PATH>\<folder_path>\\Env.bat A_H_V3 
18:27:55 [Windows] 
18:27:55 [Windows] <MY_PATH>>command...
18:27:55 [Windows] 
18:27:55 [Windows] <MY_PATH>>command...
18:27:55 [Windows] 
18:27:55 [Windows] <MY_PATH>>command... 
18:27:55 [Windows] 
18:27:55 [Windows] <MY_PATH>>command...
18:27:55 [Windows] make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
[Pipeline] [Windows] }
[Pipeline] [Windows] // script
[Pipeline] [Windows] }
[Pipeline] [Windows] // node
[Pipeline] [Windows] }
18:27:55 [Windows] Failed in branch Windows
[Pipeline] // parallel
Post stage
.
.
```

take a note that if i'm switching as follow it's printing the full list:

```
println list[i]
INSTEAD OF
bat "${flow_bm_folder}\\Env.bat ${list[i]}"
```

Any idea what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: What errors are you seeing?

Comment: How about using try-catch block within the for loop?

Comment: @mkobit - no errors but when the Env.bat fail in the first time (while the reason is no target specified for make) it is no longer continue to run the rest of the file lines.

Comment: @Curious - I'll try it when i"ll be in office and update